# Remove Polylines from over the map Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am implementing an iphone app. i have a map and array of objects that contains the coordinates to be plotted on the map. And a polyline is drawn between these point. So i want to know how to remove this polyline. not Show/Hide, but remove.

here is my code of how i am drawing it

> int pointCount = [routeLatitudes count] / 2; //routeLatitudes is the array that contains the coordinates latitude followed by longitude.

```
    MKMapPoint* pointArr = malloc(sizeof(MKMapPoint) * pointCount);

    int pointArrIndex = 0;  
    for (int idx = 0; idx < [routeLatitudes count]; idx=idx+2)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;       
        workingCoordinate.latitude=[[routeLatitudes objectAtIndex:idx] doubleValue];
        workingCoordinate.longitude=[[routeLatitudes objectAtIndex:idx+1] doubleValue];  
        MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(workingCoordinate);
        pointArr[pointArrIndex] = point;
        pointArrIndex++;
    }   

    // create the polyline based on the array of points. 
    routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointArr count:pointCount];

    [mapView addOverlay:routeLine];
    free(pointArr);
```

And to Show/Hide the polylines i created a reference **MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;**

> overlayView.hidden=false/true;

now i need to know how to remove/delete the drawn polylines.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
 [mapView removeOverlays:mapView.overlays];
```